# getting spinner values depending on selection of another spinner

Tags: java, android, json

am trying to create a functionality where i can obtain spinner values depending on the selection of a separate spinner and then post both values into a mysql database, the spinner selection is working fine but its not posting to the database, it is not generating any errors either, can someone please tell me where am going wrong? this is my java.

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
OnItemSelectedListener{
Spinner s1,s2;
Button btnCreateProduct;

private ProgressDialog pDialog;
//url to create new product
private static String url_create_product = "http://bsa.co.ke/call/create_product.php";
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    s1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    s2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    btnCreateProduct = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCreateProduct);
    s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String sp1= String.valueOf(s1.getSelectedItem());
    Toast.makeText(this, sp1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if(sp1.contentEquals("Eldoret")) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Tuskys Zion");
        list.add("Tuskys Wareng");
        list.add("Naivas Referral");
        list.add("Ukwala A");
        list.add("Ukwala A");
        list.add("Naivas Sokoni");
        list.add("Uchumi Sugar Land");
        list.add("Uchumi Super");
        list.add("Transmatt");
        list.add("Nakumatt");
        list.add("Khetias");
        list.add("Eldo");
        list.add("Uchumi Sugar Land");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);`enter code here`
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }
    if(sp1.contentEquals("Kitale")) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Suam");
        list.add("Khetias Gigamatt");
        list.add("Khetias Center Point");
        list.add("Khetias Cross Roads");
        list.add("Khetias Euro");
        list.add("Tuskys");
        list.add("Nakumatt");

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        dataAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        dataAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
        s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter2);
    }
    if(sp1.contentEquals("Kakamega")) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Yako");
        list.add("Nakumatt");
        list.add("Purchase");
        list.add("Mama Watoto");
        list.add("Tuskys Shilloah");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        dataAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        dataAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
        s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter2);
    }
    if(sp1.contentEquals("Kisii")) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Oshwal");
        list.add("Naivas");
        list.add("Tuskys Chingware");
        list.add("Uchumi");
        list.add("Nakumatt");
        list.add("Chamunda");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
          dataAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        dataAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
        s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter2);
    }

    if(sp1.contentEquals("Kericho")) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Uchumi");
        list.add("Stagematt");
        list.add("Ukwala");
        list.add("Tuskys Ndonyo");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        dataAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        dataAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
        s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter2);
    }


Button btnCreateProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreateProduct);

// button click event
btnCreateProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // creating new product in background thread
        new CreateNewProduct().execute();
    }
});
}

  /**
  * Background Async Task to Create new product
  * */
 class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

/**
 * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
 * */
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
    pDialog.show();
}

/**
 * Creating product
 * */
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
    String name =  s1.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String price = s2.getSelectedItem().toString();


    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", price));


    // getting JSON Object
    // Note that create product url accepts POST method
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
            "POST", params);

    // check log cat fro response
    Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

    // check for success tag
    try {
        int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

        if (success == 1) {
            // successfully created product
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),      MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

            // closing this screen
            finish();
        } else {
            // failed to create product
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
 * **/
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    // dismiss the dialog once done
    pDialog.dismiss();
}
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 }
 }
```

This is my string

```
  <resources>

    <string name="app_name">Spinner Example</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="lblAcc">Select Account Type</string>
    <string name="lblSubAcc">Select Account Head</string>

  <string-array name="acc_type">
        <item>Eldoret</item>
        <item>Kitale</item>
        <item>Kakamega</item>
        <item>Kisii</item>
        <item>Kericho</item>
    </string-array>

  </resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to get Selected spinner value this way:

```
String sp1= s1.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

instead of

```
String sp1= String.valueOf(s1.getSelectedItem());
```

You have used `contentEquals()` method for comparing Strings. you need to use `equals()` or `equalsIgnoreCase()` for comparing Strings.

Try this method instead of yours.

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String sp1= s1.getSelectedItem().toString();
    Toast.makeText(this, sp1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if(sp1.equalsIgnoreCase("Eldoret")) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Tuskys Zion");
        list.add("Tuskys Wareng");
        list.add("Naivas Referral");
        list.add("Ukwala A");
        list.add("Ukwala A");
        list.add("Naivas Sokoni");
        list.add("Uchumi Sugar Land");
        list.add("Uchumi Super");
        list.add("Transmatt");
        list.add("Nakumatt");
        list.add("Khetias");
        list.add("Eldo");
        list.add("Uchumi Sugar Land");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);`enter code here`
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }
    if(sp1.equalsIgnoreCase("Kitale")) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Suam");
        list.add("Khetias Gigamatt");
        list.add("Khetias Center Point");
        list.add("Khetias Cross Roads");
        list.add("Khetias Euro");
        list.add("Tuskys");
        list.add("Nakumatt");

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        dataAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        dataAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
        s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter2);
    }
    if(sp1.equalsIgnoreCase("Kakamega")) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Yako");
        list.add("Nakumatt");
        list.add("Purchase");
        list.add("Mama Watoto");
        list.add("Tuskys Shilloah");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        dataAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        dataAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
        s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter2);
    }
    if(sp1.equalsIgnoreCase("Kisii")) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Oshwal");
        list.add("Naivas");
        list.add("Tuskys Chingware");
        list.add("Uchumi");
        list.add("Nakumatt");
        list.add("Chamunda");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
          dataAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        dataAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
        s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter2);
    }

    if(sp1.equalsIgnoreCase("Kericho")) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Uchumi");
        list.add("Stagematt");
        list.add("Ukwala");
        list.add("Tuskys Ndonyo");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        dataAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        dataAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
        s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter2);
    }


Button btnCreateProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreateProduct);

// button click event
btnCreateProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // creating new product in background thread
        new CreateNewProduct().execute();
    }
});
}
```

I hope it helps!